# Dynamic connection string to Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I am exposing my repository operations through web api. Repository has been implemented with Entity framework and Unit Of Work Pattern. I have many instances of the same database. Each one represent the data of a different Client. Now the issue is how can I set the connection string dynamically through each webapi call? Should I get connection string parameter with each call ? Or I should host web Api per client ?

Comment: What is the intended lifetime of the DbContext object?  I would expect it to be a new instance for every request, but don't want to assume.

Comment: Yes a new instance for each request as requests will come randomly from different clients

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I have also exactly same requirement so need your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the information provided, I would use the same controller and look up the connection string rather than rather than hosting separate Web API instances for each client.  There would be more complexity in hosting multiple instances and given the only difference indicated is the connection string, I do not think the complexity would be justified.

The first thing we will need to do is determine which client is calling in order to get the appropriate connection string.  This could be done with tokens, headers, request data, or routing.  Routing is simplest and most generally accessible to clients, so I will demonstrate using it; however, carefully consider your requirements in deciding how you will make the determination.

```
[Route( "{clientId}" )]
public Foo Get( string clientId ) { /* ... */ }
```

Next we need to get the right `DbContext` for the client.  We want to keep using DI but that is complicated in that we do not know until after the Controller is created what connection string is needed to construct the object.  Therefore, we need to inject some form of factory rather than the object itself.  In this case we will represent this as a `Func<string, IUnitOfWork>` with the understanding it takes the 'clientId' as a string and returns an appropriately instantiated `IUnitOfWork`.  We could alternatively use a named interface for this.

```
[RoutePrefix("foo")]
public class FooController : ApiController
{  
    private Func<string, IUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory;

    public FooController( Func<string, IUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory )
    {
        this.unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
    }

    [Route( "{clientId}" )]
    public Foo Get( string clientId )
    {
        var unitOfWork = unitOfWorkFactory(clientId);
        // ...
    }
}
```

All that remains is configuring our dependency injection container to provide us that `Func<string, IUnitOfWork>`.  This could vary significantly between implementation.  The following is one possible way to do it in Autofac.

```
protected override void Load( ContainerBuilder builder )
{
    // It is expected `MyDbContext` has a constructor that takes the connection string as a parameter
    // This registration may need to be tweaked depending on what other constructors you have.
    builder.Register<MyDbContext>().ForType<DbContext>().InstancePerRequest();

    // It is expected `UnitOfWork`'s constructor takes a `DbContext` as a parameter
    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().ForType<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();

    builder.Register<Func<string, Bar>>(
        c =>
            {
                var dbContextFactory = c.Resolve<Func<string, DbContext>>();
                var unitOfWorkFactory = c.Resolve<Func<DbContext, IUnitOfWork>>();

                return clientId =>
                    {
                        // You may have injected another type to help with this
                        var connectionString = GetConnectionStringForClient(clientId);
                        return unitOfWorkFactory(dbContextFactory(connectionString));
                    };
            });
 }
```

Autofac is used since comments indicates Autofac is currently being used, though similar results would be possible with other containers.

With that the controller should be able to be instantiated and the appropriate connection string will be used for each request.

---

Example registration based on linked project:

```
builder.Register<Func<string, IEmployeeService>>(
    c =>
        {
            var dbContextFactory = c.Resolve<Func<string, IMainContext>>();
            var unitOfWorkFactory = c.Resolve<Func<IMainContext, IUnitOfWork>>();
            var repositoryFactory = c.Resolve<Func<IMainContext, IEmployeeRepository>>();
            var serviceFactory = c.Resolve<Func<IUnitOfWork, IEmployeeService>>();

            return clientId =>
                {
                    // You may have injected another type to help with this
                    var connectionString = GetConnectionStringForClient(clientId);

                    IMainContext dbContext = dbContextFactory(connectionString);
                    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = unitOfWorkFactory(dbContext);
                    IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository = repositoryFactory(dbContext);
                    unitOfWork.employeeRepositoty = employeeRepository;

                    return serviceFactory(unitOfWork);
                };
        });
```

If you find the registration grows too cumbersome because of needing to do a little wiring manually, you probably need to look at updating (or creating a new) container after you have determined the client so that you can rely more on the container.

Comment: Many thanks , here is the link to a sample project I have created to demonstrate the architecture I am using https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f2leb6i8kmggef2/AAC8rGfkeD73e19HX9Vf_qZYa?dl=0

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications It looks like the above would apply there.  However, you are using MVC rather than WebAPI as the question indicates (and this answer shows) though you should still be able to use attribute routing if you decide on that route.  It does not appear you have yet decided how you will determine the client.

Comment: You have one more class between the database and the controller (the Service) and that can be handled in registration in exactly the same way as shown above.

Comment: Actual project is a web Api project. This is just a sample to show how Repository and Unit of work are interacting with ServiceFacade layer

Comment: So we will have a service Factory instead of UnitOfWork Factory ? Context is being injected into both Repository and UnitOfWork how that can be handled with removing DI?

Comment: Many thanks, I will give this a go and let you know . I tried another way of doing this here is the https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kqd1wo3d0r67g2k/AAA9V1INK319KJEQTHOqgHgFa?dl=0 in this example I am using Service Factory. Please have a look

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications I see no reason the implementation you started cannot be made to work.  It much utilizes the same principles, you are just writing a factory that constructs the objects without the assistance of DI container.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the connectionstring per DbContext instance

Example:

```
public class AwesomeContext : DbContext
{
    public AwesomeContext (string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<AwesomePeople> AwesomePeoples { get; set; }
}
```

And then use your DbContext like this:

```
   using(AwesomeContext context = new AwesomeContext("newConnectionString"))
   {
     return context.AwesomePeoples.ToList();
   }
```

Depending on how many ConnectionStrings there are you can make a DB table for the client / constring mapping or save it in the solution (array for example).

**If you can't/don't want to change the constructor you can do it later as well**

Add this to your DbContext override:

```
    public void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
    {
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }
```

And call the method before you do any DB operations:

```
   using(AwesomeContext context = new AwesomeContext())
   {

    context.SetConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
    return context.AwesomePeoples.ToList();

   }
```

Comment: I am injecting my context through interface and autofac. It's  like Public Class AwesomeContext: DbContext, IAwesomeContext

Comment: I updated the answer so you can change the connectionstring even if you are injecting the context

Comment: I am injecting IAwesomeContext not DbContext

Comment: I can't look in your code (you need to provide examples), but you can change my example to your implementation. All you need to do is add the SetConnectionString method to the interface and implement it in your specific context class. Then call the method on the injected variable

Comment: Code example is here stackoverflow.com/q/30404108/1711287 . I have eloborated it further

Comment: You are linking to this question

Comment: both questions are mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80880/discussion-between-matthijsb-and-intheworldofcodingapplications).

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications can you post some of your code? Because I have it working here

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f2leb6i8kmggef2/AAC8rGfkeD73e19HX9Vf_qZYa?dl=0     Here is the sample solution

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications This should work: https://gist.github.com/matthijsbreemans/2a2cbd24d11492e71af2

Comment: What about having a factory that returns dbcontext based on passed connection string ? Which method would you prefer ?

Comment: I wouldn't change the connectionstring at all at runtime

Comment: So you would prefer a factory that returns DbContext object based on Connection String?